# I need help with proving $\cos(\arcsin(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

As I've said I need help with this particular trigonometric identity:

$$\cos(\arcsin(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$$

I've tried finding a proof for it but I had no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem definition already gives you a hint of how to solve it. There's sine and cosine and something squared ... Do you know about any identities with sines and cosines and them squared?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Well I wanted to make a sine function out of this, by perhaps adding pi/2 to the function in the brackets, but that just makes things more complicated to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\cos^2(\arcsin(x))+x^2=\cos^2(\arcsin(x))+\sin^2(\arcsin(x))=1$, hence

$\cos^2(\arcsin(x))=1-x^2$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Of course, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you set $\alpha=\arcsin x$, then $x=\sin\alpha$ and $-\pi/2\le\alpha\le\pi/2$.

Therefore the proposed identity becomes
$$
\cos\alpha=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha}
$$
which is true because $\cos\alpha\ge0$ when $-\pi/2\le\alpha\le\pi/2$ and we know that $\cos^2\alpha=1-\sin^2\alpha$.

<sup>Be careful in spelling out the condition $\alpha\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, because a claim such as $\cos\alpha=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha}$ is false in general.</sup>

---

The analytic proof considering $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}-\cos\arcsin x$ seems a bit more complicated, but here it is:
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sin\arcsin x=0
$$
for $-1<x<1$. By continuity, the function $f$ is constant on $[-1,1]$. Since $f(0)=0$ we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Given a right triangle with hypotenuse $1$, angle $\theta$, opposite leg $x$ and adjacent leg $y$, we have
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 1\\
\arcsin(x) = \theta\\
\cos(\theta) = y
$$
If we put these together in the right order, we get your identity.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, for $|x|\leq 1,$ in $\Bbb R^2 $  let $O=(0,0), $ $ A=(\sqrt {1-x^2}\;, x), $ and $ B=(\sqrt {1-x^2},x). $ Then $\angle AOB$ (evaluated as  negative if $x<0$) is $\arcsin x.$ And $|\angle AOB|\leq \pi /2.$ So $\cos \angle AOB= OB/OA=OB=\sqrt {1-x^2}\;.$